# How do I prevent lag in the Nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

So I visited the nether in the mod pack Big Dig, and now the game is literally unplayable for me. I get massive lag spikes, and I can't do anything. It is quite horrible.

Is there a way of deleting the nether file out of my save so I could maybe prevent the lag?

I was getting around 100fps before I went to the nether, and I had three quarries running, so I believe that deleting any recollection of going to the nether (besides items) should fix it. I have literally spent like five hours on this world and didn't go to the nether, because I never had to, and now I can't even play.

Comment: Are your quarries in the nether?

Comment: There is a way to delete the nether, but no promises that it will fix your issue. This link should help lead the way: http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/815611-regenerate-the-nether/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try allocating more memory to minecraft through java. You can make a .bat file in the same map as minecraft.exe with this line:

start /high javaw -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -jar minecraft.exe

or

java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar "Minecraft.exe"

You could play with the numbers to make it optimal for yourself. Of course you can not allocate more space then your system supports. To find out r-mouse on "my computer" in the start window and press properties. To make a file like this you just create a .txt file, edit it and paste in the line. Then rename the file extension to .bat like minecraft.bat.

You might need to install java SDK or java SE first if you do not have that yet. To see if you ave java or javaw you can open cmd by typing "cmd" in run program and there type in java or javaw, java should give you a list of options javaw should not return anything .  Here is some more reference as to how to allocate more memory.

http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1395030-tutorial-allocate-more-memory-for-minecraft/

Comment: If Minecraft runs at all then Java and JavaW are already installed.

Comment: I didn't had to either, i use the SDK. I was simply saying what the sources suggest on how to allocate more memory and have a complete answer for everyone.

Comment: No, I mean the paragraph that starts "You might need to install..." is wrong: you *never* have to install anything, since Minecraft already uses and can't run without the `java` or `javaw` commands. They come with Java SE, which you have to have to run Minecraft.

Comment: I have a laptop with a clean install so i tested it and you seem to be right, when you try to install MC it brings you to the java website and when you installed java you have access to it from the MC folder. But there are sources on internet stating that you need java SE or SDK in "how to allocate more memory to minecraft" tutorials (check source i posted). I just wanted my answer to be complete so i added it there, it might be redundant or it just might help somebody for example someone that runs a old version of java.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the accepted answer, it is possible to configure the JVM arguments directly in the launcher:

1. Open the Minecraft launcher.
2. Select the profile you want to configure, or create a new one.
3. Click "Edit profile".
4. Enable "JVM Arguments".
5. Configure the arguments to allocate more memory, for example: "-Xmx2048M -Xms2048M"
6. Click "Save profile".